# Probability that a random matrix will have full column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices

It is known that for a random matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times K}$ with $M>K$, if each element is i.i.d. Gaussian generated, then $A$ has full column rank with probability one.

Now, assume that each element of $A$ is in the form of $e^{j\theta}$, where $\theta$'s are i.i.d. uniformly distributed in $(0,2\pi)$. Can I prove that $A$ has full column rank, with probability one? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the first fact?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a result of this form is true very generally. It's equivalent to prove that $k$ vectors $v_1, \dots v_k \in \mathbb{C}^m$ chosen iid wrt the distribution given by $e^{i \theta}$ in each coordinate are linearly independent with probability $1$.

This is true with a much more general distribution on random vectors: it suffices for the vectors to be chosen iid wrt any distribution on $\mathbb{C}^m$ such that the probability of the vector lying in any particular hyperplane through the origin is zero. A large class of examples is any distribution with a continuous pdf such that the induced distribution on the unit sphere given by sampling a random vector and scaling it to unit length also has a continuous pdf which is nowhere zero; in any case your distribution qualifies.

To prove this we sample the vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots$ one at a time, observing that at each step $\text{span}(v_1, \dots v_i)$ is at most an $i$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^m$, and so by hypothesis $v_{i+1}$ avoids it with probability $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any reference that I can cite (I am writing a paper and want to use this result directly). Thank you.

Comment: BTW,  is identical very important here? If the amplitude of each entry is fixed but not identical to each other, does this result still apply?

Comment: Identical isn't important, and neither is independent; you just need the distribution of each vector conditional on the previous ones to have the above property. I don't have a reference.