# Why is the probability of a gaussian random vector being a linear combination of other random vectors not non-zero

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

It is known that the probability of a gaussian random matrix being full rank is 1 (e.g. here: [Probability that a random matrix will have full column rank?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545417/probability-that-a-random-matrix-will-have-full-column-rank)).

Therefore the probability of a gaussian random vector (i.i.d gaussian entries) being a linear combination of other fixed vectors is should also be zero. I have a more specific subset, I want to show that the probability of the vector being in the set of all combinations of other fixed vectors so that the weights add up to 1 is zero. So I just tried to prove it for $d=2$ (dimensionality) and $n=2$ fixed vectors. I must have made a fundamental error, because it's not zero.

\begin{align}
&\mathcal{P}(X = \alpha \cdot w_1 + (1-\alpha) \cdot w_2, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}) \\
&=\int_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}f_{X_1}(\alpha \cdot [w_1]_1 + (1-\alpha) \cdot [w_2]_1) \cdot f_{X_2}(\alpha \cdot [w_1]_2 + (1-\alpha) \cdot [w_2]_2) d \alpha \\
&=\int_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}f_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(\alpha \cdot [w_1]_1 + (1-\alpha) \cdot [w_2]_1) \cdot f_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(\alpha \cdot [w_1]_2 + (1-\alpha) \cdot [w_2]_2) d \alpha \\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot \pi}\int_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}((\alpha \cdot [w_1]_2 + (1-\alpha) \cdot [w_2]_2)^2 + (\alpha \cdot [w_1]_2 + (1-\alpha) \cdot [w_2]_2)^2)} d \alpha \\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot \pi}\int_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}([w_1]_1 - [w_2]_1)^2([w_1]_2 - [w_2]_2)^2\alpha^2} d \alpha \\
&> 0 \text{ since it's a gaussian integral}
\end{align}

where am I wrong?

Comment: I didn’t read what you wrote, but all you end up saying is that $P(\text{something})\geq 0$. There is no contradiction

Comment: sorry, should have been a strictly greater than! will edit

Comment: Can you justify the first equality? It already seems suspicious that it should hold. By the way, a line has measure zero, and since a (nonsingular) Gaussian vector has a density…

Comment: for a random variable $X$ with pdf $f_X$, we have
$$\Pr(X\in A) = \int_{x\in A}f_X(x)\ dx. $$
This is not what you have written.

Comment: sorry for being dense, but why not?

Comment: does this not hold? 
$$\int_{x \in \{\alpha \cdot w_1 + (1-\alpha) \cdot w_2, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}}f_X(x)dx=\int_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}f_X(\alpha \cdot w_1 + (1-\alpha) \cdot w_2, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\})d\alpha$$

Comment: Well clearly it doesn’t hold because it leads to the wrong result

Comment: I also strongly suspect that but I am not sure why. I try to figure it out myself but I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to show that the probability of the vector being in the set of all combinations of other fixed vectors so that the weights add up to 1 is zero.

The set $\{ \alpha w_1 + (1-\alpha)w_2  : \alpha \in \mathbb R\}$
is exactly the line passing through the points $w_1$ and $w_2$ since  $$\alpha w_1 + (1-\alpha)w_2  = \alpha(w_1-w_2) + w_2.$$

This line $L$ has no area as subset of $\mathbb R^2$ so by definition the integral of any function on $L$ is equal to $0$.

Concerning your calculuations you should be careful. It is not because you have a parametrization $\gamma : \mathbb R \to L :  \alpha  \mapsto \alpha w_1 + (1-\alpha w_2)$ with $\gamma (\mathbb R) = L$ that you can write

$$ \int_{\gamma(\mathbb R)} f(x) dx = \int_{\alpha \in  \mathbb R} f \circ \gamma(\alpha ) d\alpha$$

This is not at all how we do changes of variables in multivariable calculus !

Comment: thanks! It's been a few years, amazing how you can forget this