Rank of a random matrix $A=B^T B$ where $ B$ is a random matrix
I am working on the rank of a random matrix (by random, I mean each element of the matrix could come from a certain distribution (could be normal)). Suppose $A= B^T B$, where $B$ is a $n \times m$ random matrix with $n>m$. So my questions are: (1) Can I assume the matrix $B$ is full rank $m$ even if it is random? If so, under what conditions I can do so. (2) If $B$ is full rank of $m$, then can I claim $A= B^T B$ is of full rank $m$ such that it is invertible?
I am not familiar with random matrix theory, but this is the issue arising from my research. Thanks a lot!

Why not run a simulation or two, a bit of experimentation to help develop insight?

(1) Yes it is full rank. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2545625/3060 (2) yes, use the SVD

Thanks for the link. After checking the link, I found that most of the results are based on certain distribution of $B$, e.g., normal or uniform. Can this result be generalized to other distributions? If so, do I have a reference to cite since I am writing a paper on this. Many thanks!

In my simulations, they are full rank, but I need a certain theory to assume or show $A$ is full rank for my paper. Thanks for your insights.

Assuming the elements are random, and in particular not necessarily independent nor identical, you'll need to introduce some other conditions. It might be helpful to look at degenerate distributions, for example $B_{11}$ being zero or one with some probability and all other elements always zero.

Thanks for your insights. Do you mind sharing some books or references for me to check?

Look up Terence Tao's works on universality of properties for random matrices. He proves that most properties are common to most distributions
